# onclick addClass, how to remove class again

Tags: jquery, toggle

I've got this piece of code to toggle a side panel:

```
$(".example_wrapper_panel_link").click(function() { 
$(".example_wrapper").addClass('example_wrapper_active'); 
$(".example_wrapper_panel").animate({width: "toggle"}, 400);
```

The addClass is working fine, but now when I click again to hide the div, I want to remove the  added class again.

Can't seem to find the solution for this case.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: do you want to alternate the presence of that class? or do you want just to add once and remove once?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use `.toggleClass()` method.

```
$(".example_wrapper_panel_link").click(function() { 
   // instead of addClass() just use toggleClass()
   $(".example_wrapper").toggleClass('example_wrapper_active'); 
   $(".example_wrapper_panel").animate({width: "toggle"}, 400);
});
```

**[`.toggleClass()`](http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass)** will add class to target if not exists and remove it again if exists.

Comment: thanks a lot this is the right answer, will accept in 6 minutes :)

Answer (score 2):

`.removeClass()` removes a given class.

`.toggleClass()` toggles a given class, which means that it'll add that class if missing, otherwise it will remove it.

So your handler may become as simple as:

```
$(".example_wrapper").toggleClass('example_wrapper_active');
```

Documentation for [`removeClass()`](http://api.jquery.com/removeClass/) and for [`toggleClass()`](http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/)

Answer (score 1):

`.removeClass('class');` should do it, [see the jQuery API here](http://api.jquery.com/removeClass/). If you're interested in alternating, `.toggleClass('class');` may be more appropriate.

Answer (score 1):

try using .toggleClass.

```
$(".example_wrapper").toggleClass('example_wrapper_active');
```

Answer (score 0):

You should go for `.toggleClass()` instead of `.addClass()` and `.removeClass()`.